# How to prevent this method from calling too often while it runs

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, twilio, multiple-conditions

So I have a method A which basically checks to see what the current state of UISwitches are and then alerts the user via a text-SMS service API. However; since it is constantly checking the state of the pins I do not want it to send the text 50000 times (spamming the SMS service); the final FOR loop within this method is the one that is checking to see if it should check the user; however with it's current state it constantly spams whenever the app is running.

Thanks if you need more clarification please ask.

Method A:

```
- (void)setInput:(NCDigitalInput *)input
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *baseString;
        uint8_t value = input.value;
        self.inputLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%0.2X",value];
        for (UISwitch *temp in switchArrayIn)
        {
            temp.on = (value & 1);
            value >>= 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<switchArrayIn.count; i++){
            if(![defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",i]] && ([[switchArrayIn objectAtIndex:i] isOn]) && ([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dBool",i]]) && ([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInputAlertOn%dBool",i]])){
                [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted"];
                baseString = [defaults objectForKey:@"digitalInput%d"];
                NSString *stringSMS = [baseString stringByAppendingString:@" has turned on"];
                [self digitalSMSCheck:i :stringSMS];
            }
            if(![defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",i]] && !([[switchArrayIn objectAtIndex:i] isOn]) && ([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dBool",i]]) && ([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInputAlertOff%dBool",i]])){
                [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted"];
                baseString = [defaults objectForKey:@"digitalInput%d"];
                NSString *stringSMS = [baseString stringByAppendingString:@" has turned off"];

                [self digitalSMSCheck:i :stringSMS];
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just have a method that gets called whenever the value of a UISwitch changes, rather than checking each UISwitch in a loop?

Comment: This is basically a fail-safe that alerts the user in the event the switch turns off on its own (which will happen given what the application is used for).

Comment: It's not clear why you can't detect changes of the switches. It all happens in your app, right? It's either user events or your code that changes the switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your design. Polling is bad, and not necessary.

Attach IBActions to each switch.

Make the switch's action methods set properties. If you have a lot of switches you can put tags on each switch and have a single method that handles all of them.

Then you can either create custom setters on your properties, or use key-value observing to watch for changes in the host properties. Take a look at the "Introduction to Key-Value Observing Programming Guide" in the Xcode docs for a description of how this works.

Which approach is better depends on the details of your application, plus your personal taste. KVC is a little slower than other methods, but it works well.

Comment: I have KVC implemented as is implied by my code; however I need to poll (unless there is another way) the switches because it is listening for a non-user change which can happen given the applications' purpose. In the event a non-user change does occur wouldn't polling be the only way to tell?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. What is a "non-user change", and what is changing? Do you have state variables that can change due to network events, input from a hardware device, or something else? Also, you said "I have KVC implemented as is implied by my code..." What code? You haven't posted any code. You need to provide a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do, and an explanation of the terms you're using. "...it is constantly checking the state of the pins..." What pins? What are they? How can the "pins" change without user interaction?

Comment: a non-user change is a change made by an external device that reads values into the ipod; and a change would occur if that device fails. I.E.; a user turns UISwitch 0 on, and it fails from the hardware side of things and tells the switch to turn off and alerts the user it has failed... a failure can be caused by a wide variety of hardware-related issues.

Comment: Ok, how is "the hardware side" interfacing wit the iOS device, and with your app? Still not enough info.

Comment: Via a lightning cable connection to the application interfacing with a custom-built framework to interact with the hardware. It's merely a controlling board for factory systems. So for instance; the hardware fails which means the board that is connected to the hardware via the various solder points would stop receiving voltages at their respective ports. These ports then tell the hardware to tell the iPod which tells the application it failed which sends and SMS to the user that the hardware has failed.

Comment: So all the while the board is using the application to read the voltage levels and current status of various electrical inputs/pins. These inputs/pins will always be checked until they potentially fail; and if they do fail - they shut off the UISwitch corresponding to their pin which shuts down power/reading to the pin on the board and alerts the user via Twilio SMS.

Comment: SO, now say the hardware fails; but the voltage is a bit jumpy. The application needs to know to not send several hundred SMS messages for each voltage jump.

Comment: You are painting a pretty muddy picture of how it all works. You need to go back and edit your original question to provide a clear picture of the flow of control. What triggers updates from the hardware? Is your  setInput method called by the hardware driver? How do you tell when an input has failed? Don't you need to keep track of which inputs are sending valid data and which are not, on a pin-by-pin basis, and only send status messages for those pins that ARE sending valid data? And shouldn't that valid/invalid state be in iVars, not switch states?

Comment: Never mind; you're just going to continuously bash whatever I say no matter how clear I make it. You've done it before. Negativity never pays my friend. Just forget about the question.